# How do I re-add Rhythmbox to the sound menu?

Tags: rhythmbox, indicator-sound

A strange think happened in rhythmbox, after a crash, rhythmbox doesn't shows anymore in the sound menu.

If I switch to a guess session, it is OK.
I tried to reinstall, but it didn't solve.

Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: other strange think, I can't find rythmbox in the search field in the dash menu. I can find rhythmbox in the installed parogramme list but if I click on it, it does not work.I must open rhythmbox-client in the user/bin folder to open it.

Comment: Your best bet is to open rhythmbox through a terminal and see what kind of error it is spewing out. Open a terminal and type: rhymthbox and then hopefully a useful error message will appear which you can then use to google it. If not error message appears try rhythmbox -d instead, although that will output a lot of messages, so it'll probably be harder to find the error.

Comment: If I enter Rhythmbox in a terminal, I get this "(rhythmbox:4601): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_provider_get_style_property: assertion `g_type_is_a (gtk_widget_path_get_object_type (path), pspec->owner_type)' failed

Answer (score 2):

If it's not showing up in the sound indicator any more, the three most likely reasons are

1. The plug-in got disabled/removed
2. A problem exists in the sound menu itself
3. A problem exists in communication between Rhythmbox and the sound menu

Check that the plug-in is enabled under `Edit`->`Plugins` (I think the support is integrated with the Notifications plug-in, and there are settings for it to disable the tray icon/sound indicator support, or pop-up notifications). You can also log out, wait a minute (some of the services take a few seconds to exit after logging out), and log back in. This will restart all the related services and Unity, so that if some underlying service was the cause, the problem should just go away.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to remove the rhythmbox folder before reinstalling it? or removing  rhythmbox with the --purge option? If not, the same configurations will be used even if you remove and install the application

Comment: yes, I did both but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to your home folder in Nautilus, press CTRL + H to show hidden folders, and look for `.rhythmbox`. Backup it to another location, then delete this folder. Restart Rhythmbox. You'll lose your personal settings, but at least you'll have a working Rhythmbox again. If you want to revert to your old settings at any point, again delete the .`rhythmbox` folder and put the backed-up `.rhythmbox` folder there.

Comment: I did but still not working

Comment: If I create a new user profile, I can see The rhythmbox control in the sound menu.The issue seams to be my user preferences.

Comment: OK, try to do the same procedure I mentioned earlier, but now with the folder `~/.config/rhythmbox` (if it exists).

Comment: Hi, can't find <~/.config/rhythmbox>, something must be corrupted in under this sessionprofile .I give up, I created a new session profile and it is OK. Strange Ubuntu behavior !